# How to use a previously calculated set of clusters to start EM Clustering in R?

Tags: r, clustering, hierarchical-clustering, bic

I have performed Hierarchical Clustering on a data set. I would now like to compare the BIC of the clustering methods. The process involves using the clusters you have determined to act as your starting point for EM clustering and determine the BIC of this.

I am using the mclust package in R and would like to know how to use my pre-existing clusters to act as the starting point?

My reading has so far only found the ability to change the initialization to 'hcPairs' or 'subset' which aren't what I'm looking for!

Comment: You can modify the code to add missing functionality. And if you share the extensions, others may be thankful.